# ValueError: could not convert string to float.

Tags: python

I'm trying to read in a text file and turn the input into lists:

```
model = open('Grids/Dusty_AGN/Z'+Z+'_n'+n+'_alp-'+alpha+'_fluxes.txt','r')

Hafluxfile = model.readline() + model.readline() + model.readline() ; the first three lines of the file contain the values that I need

Haflux = []

Haflux.append([float(x) for x in Hafluxfile.split(' ')])
```

If I `print Hafluxfile`, this is what I see:

```
  2.97500      2.94300      2.92700      2.91800      2.90700      2.90200
  2.89300      2.87700      2.86700      2.87000      2.89900      2.93500
  2.91900
```

and then I end up with this error message when trying to append the list `Haflux`:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

and no, there is nothing that I haven't included beyond the colon, it seems to be telling me that white space is preventing it from getting to the first number? I don't know how to work around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *multiple spaces* between the items. Don't specify the separator when calling [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

And, it looks like you also have leading and trailing spaces which you can trim with [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
[float(x) for x in Hafluxfile.strip().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are getting some empty elements.

```
Haflux.append([float(str(x)) for x in Hafluxfile.split(' ') if len(x)>1])
```

This will take care of them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should concatenate your path component using `+`, instead you should use the [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function. That being said to do this I would use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

```
import os
import csv

haflux = []
filename = os.path.join('Grids/Dusty_AGN/Z', Z, '_n', n, '_alp-', alpha, '_fluxes.txt')
with open('filename') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for n in range(3):
        haflux.append([float(i) for i in next(reader) if i])

print(haflux)
#  [[2.975, 2.943, 2.927, 2.918, 2.907, 2.902], [2.893, 2.877, 2.867, 2.87, 2.899, 2.935], [2.919]]
```

Answer (score -1):

From my very limited understanding of Python, it is smart enough to convert the string to a float automatically provided that there is no other character present in the string that is non-numerical. You should try iterating over your file and call `isDigit()` on each of your number to see if there are any hidden new-line characters or something of that sort. Or is the problem that it's not iterating over the list at all?